# Simple mermaid graph fails

Tags: javascript, html, mermaid

I tried to run the [example](http://knsv.github.io/mermaid/#flowcharts-basic-syntax) from the mermaid site (a [working copy](http://codepen.io/WoJWoJ/pen/rxrvBO) is on codepen.io):

```
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/knsv/mermaid/0.5.1/dist/mermaid.min.js"></script>
<script>mermaid.initialize({startOnLoad:true});</script>

<div class="mermaid">

graph TD;
    A-->B;
    A-->C;
    B-->D;
    C-->D;

</div>
```

The output is:

[image]

At the same time, a [sequence diagram works great](http://codepen.io/WoJWoJ/pen/eJjrRz).

Where is the problem with the basic example?

## Update

The issue was with Chrome 48 compatibility. It is fixed by using the latest `js` file:

```
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/knsv/mermaid/master/dist/mermaid.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/knsv/mermaid/master/dist/mermaid.css">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks ok in Safari:

[image: Screenshot of the resulting graph]

The only thing that was missing for me was the line colour, but adding this css fixed that:

```
path {
  stroke: black;
}
```

Comment: Ha. I tried http://codepen.io/WoJWoJ/pen/rxrvBO on Firefox and the graph is visible. It must be a problem with Chome (which is a no-go in usage), I will fill a bug report. Thanks.

Comment: I filed a bug but it was deleted (not closed) -- not sure why. Anyway the solution is to use the latest version of `mermaid` from github, per the update to my question.