# mermaid library graph not getting rendered in angular2

Tags: angular, mermaid

I need to represent a simple graph with node and edges in one of my components in angular2. I tried the following:

In index.html:

```
 <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/knsv/mermaid/master/dist/mermaid.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/knsv/mermaid/master/dist/mermaid.css">
```

In transfer.component.html:

```
<script>mermaid.initialize({startOnLoad:true});</script>
<div class="mermaid">
  mermaid editor

  graph TD;
  A-->B;
  A-->C;
  B-->D;
  C-->D;

</div>
```

But the graph is not getting rendered. I get the following output:

[Mermaid Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpUwN.png)

Can anybody please point out what am I doing wrong?
I already referred to the following issue: [Simple mermaid graph fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35156863/simple-mermaid-graph-fails/35159236#35159236)
and have included the latest mermaid files, but still not getting the output.

- Browser: Chrome Version 61.0.3163.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- Angular versions: @angular/cli: 1.3.1 node: 6.11.2 os: linux x64

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Angular sanitizes script tags in html templates. You'll need to add `<script>mermaid.initialize({startOnLoad:true});</script>` to your index.html or somewhere in your typescript. For example you could add it to the ngOnInit lifecycle of your transfer.component

```
// transfer.component.ts
declare const mermaid;

export class TransferComponent implements OnInit {
    ngOnInit(){
        mermaid.initialize({startOnLoad:true});
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @LLai. I tried as per your response but getting the following error now: mermaid.initialize is not a function. I think it is not recognizing mermaid library. Any input?

Comment: @JasjeetKaur Are you using the component method I posted? If so did you declare mermaid at the top of your component file `declare const mermaid;`

Comment: yes I did. On the top of the page: `declare const mermaid`;

Comment: @JasjeetKaur can you confirm that mermaid is loading properly?

Comment: How to confirm that? I included the link to the file in index.html:
`<script src="http://www.sveido.com/mermaid/dist/mermaid.full.js"></script>`

Comment: @JasjeetKaur Do you see the script loading in the network tab of the browsers debug tools? In the console is there a global `mermaid` variable defined?

Comment: Thanks. There was an error in the script file I was referencing. The error is removed but the graph is still not rendered. I am getting the same output as mentioned in the problem statement.

Comment: @JasjeetKaur hmm if you are loading the script file and calling that `mermaid.initialize` it should be rendering some kind of svg. The script is definitely loading?

Comment: @JasjeetKaur odd, I can get it to work on my local, but can't get it to render on plnkr

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did and it is working fine for me....

Added below lines of code in my Index.html

```
<script src="./assets/js/mermaid.js"></script>
<script>mermaid.initialize({startOnLoad:true});</script>
```

In my component HTML file, I simply added statement like this to display the graph

```
<div class="mermaid">
  graph TD;
  A-->B;
  A-->C;
  B-->D;
  C-->D;
</div>
```

It is working as expected.